# Fastest way to retrieve values from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>` with the following data:

```
123, "Do this"
234, "Do that"
345, "Do something"
123, "Do that"
567, "Do anything"
234, "Do something"
```

What's the best way for me to retrieve only the values for any given key? Say, I want to get only the values for 123.

Comment: Never thought about that. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) object cannot have multiple items with the same key. Instead, you want to use [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx).

The code might look something like this:

```
var items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, String>>();

items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(123, "Do this"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(234, "Do that"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(345, "Do something"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(123, "Do that"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(567, "Do anything"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(234, "Do something"));

// This is the key you are looking for
int desiredValue = 123;

foreach (var v in items.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == desiredValue))
{
    // Access the values you need here
    Console.WriteLine(v.Value);
}
```

Where the output would be:

```
Do this 
Do that
```

You can see this example in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VhS0mV). Happy coding :)

Comment: Why would you talk about lookup and then *not* actually use it?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have multiple different values grouped under one key you probably have to change the structure of your dictionary to something like this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

You then initialize the list for each new key or if the key's already there you add the item to the list.

```
if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    myDictionary[myKey] = new List<string();
}
myDictionary[myKey].Add(myItem);
```

And you get the items in a standard way:

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    var results = myDictionary[myKey];
}
```

This will give you a list that you can then query to see what items have been returned.

Answer (score 1):

See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication61
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>() {
               {123, new List<string>() {"Do this", "Do that"}},
               {234, new List<string>() {"Do that", "Do something"}},
               {345, new List<string>() {"Do something"}},
               {567, new List<string>() {"Do anything"}}
            };

            List<string> results = dict[123];

        }

    }
}
```